# MySQL 5.7 DISTINCT PERFORMANCE

Tags: query-performance, mysql-5.7

I have a big table with ~6M rows. I am trying to optimize the search queries of that table. I have created another table which contain all of the searchable fields and update the table with triggers when necessary.

1. I don't add this field to the search table and use JOIN for filtering. This increase the execution time.

```
CREATE TABLE event_entities_mv AS
SELECT ee.event_id,
       ee.event_date,
       e.status,
       e.user

FROM event_entities ee
         JOIN events e ON ee.event_id = e.id;

CREATE INDEX event_date_idx ON event_entities_mv (event_date, event_id);

SELECT e.id, e.event_date
FROM event_entities_mv e
     JOIN entities_fields ef ON e.id = ef.entity_id 
     WHERE ef.field_id = :fieldId
     AND (e.event_date, e.id) > (:prevDate, :prevId)
ORDER BY e.event_date ASC, e.id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

2. I can use LEFT JOIN while creating the search table which will cause duplicates and  will need to use `DISTINCT(id)` in my search queries.

```
CREATE TABLE event_entities_mv AS
SELECT ee.event_id,
       ee.event_date,
       e.status,
       e.user,
       ef.field_id

FROM event_entities ee
         JOIN events e ON ee.event_id = e.id
         LEFT JOIN event_fields ef ON e.id = ef.event_id;

CREATE INDEX event_date_idx ON event_entities_mv (event_date, event_id);
CREATE INDEX event_field_idx ON event_entities_mv (field_id, event_date, event_id);

SELECT DISTINCT(e.id), e.event_date
FROM event_entities_mv e
     WHERE e.field_id = :fieldId
     AND (e.event_date, e.id) > (:prevDate, :prevId)
ORDER BY e.event_date ASC, e.id ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Searching with `fieldId` doesn't happen much in reality so it might be acceptable to search with join when needed. I am wondering if using `DISTINCT` will cause any big performance issues?

Comment: Just an aside: `DISTINCT (column), another_column` doesn't do what you probably think it does.  It's actually the same as `DISTINCT column, another_column`, i.e. a set of distinct `(column, another_column)` pairs, where either `column` or `another_column` can occur more than once (just not in the same combination). In other words, `DISTINCT` [always applies to entire rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d0aa960524a6d83bb81c8f24579ee9d2&hide=3), never to parts of rows.